# How does the .NET Framework assign thread IDs?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio, async-await

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531672/dying-thread-in-java). The code in that question generated multiple threads inside a loop, and the OP there observed that the thread ID in their logging seemed to keep increasing over time. That question was about Java, but it got me thinking: how do the JVM and .NET Framework assign thread IDs in the first place? I'm particularly interested in this for cases like the OP describes in his post (for verifying that threads are actually being created and destroyed as expected) as well as for more context on how to interpret the Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools logs. I'm also interested for my own understanding of how the framework is working.

I'm asking here primarily about the .NET Framework because it would probably be too broad to ask about both at once (although I'd definitely be glad to hear details about the JVM, too). But, here's an example of the log I was getting in the Events tab of the Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools:

**Program output**: The thread 0x44c has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Here are a few of the thread IDs in order:

```
0xcb0
0x2c4c
0x2c5c
0x1b10
0x1a60
0x27b4
0x2b80
0x2e04
```

Those don't appear to be especially sequential. That log isn't, in and of itself, terribly informative without, for example, getting more context from the Threads window in Visual Studio, so I'm hoping that understanding more about how these are being assigned in the first place will give a little more context for these events.

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
await jobs.AsyncForEach(async delegate (Job job)
    {
       // Do some stuff, some of which involves async/await HttpClient calls to a RESTful API
    }, GlobalSettings.maxDegreeOfParallelism);
```

`jobs` is of type `List<Job>`, `GlobalSettings.maxDegreeOfParallelism` is a `const int` specifying the maximum degree of parallelism (due to the API throttle from our vendor), and `AsyncForEach` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static async Task AsyncForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, Task> action, int degreeOfParallelism)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (T item in enumerable)
    {
        if (tasks.Count >= degreeOfParallelism)
        {
            await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

            tasks = tasks.Where(t => !t.IsCompleted).ToList();
        }

        Task actionTask = action(item);

        tasks.Add(actionTask);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

This could currently run in one of three environments: a WPF application, a console application, or a unit test. The log I showed here is from a unit test run, but a console application logs seem very similar.

I do realize that `async`/`await` works somewhat differently in cases like this, and that there are no explicit guarantees as to which thread(s) the async code will run on if there's no synchronization context; for what it's worth, though, I'm not explicitly assigning any code to its own thread with `new Thread`, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, or `Task.Run` at any point in this code.

When I searched for this on Google, I saw documentation on the difference between a Managed Thread ID as well as how to get the ID from a thread. However, these don't really answer the question of how the .NET Framework came up with those in the first place.

I'm also well aware of the Visual Studio Threads window, which shows the ID, associated process, Managed ID, Category, Name, and Location of threads. This also doesn't exactly answer the question of how the framework assigned those to begin with.

Comment: The CLR simply starts at 1 and counts up.  But you are looking at the operating system thread ID, the framework is not involved with it at all and you only ever see them from debugger notifications.  How it picks them is intentionally undocumented.  That the debugger does not show the managed ID in its notifications is arguably a flaw.

Comment: @HansPassant That could probably be an answer. It's a very constructive piece of information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't.
There are two different entities: *native* threads, which are created by an Operating System, and *managed* threads, which are created by CLR. Thread ID comes from the OS, ManagedThreadID comes from the CLR. Both are counters, through OS has much larger pool of thread objects at the time when CLR start. Thread IDs are unique per entire OS, CLR threads are unique just per process. 

 Managed thread is essentially a data structure, which is stored in native thread's TLS-memory section, and CLR can edit it, therefore allowing managed thread to switch from one native thread to another and host multiple managed threads atop one native thread via fiber API. You can use `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity` to stick managed thread to the same native thread. Also, it is essential for desktop applications to have their main managed thread to map to the same native thread (OS sends messages for repaint, keyboard events and multiple other things to specific  native thread's message loop, CLR picks it up), therefore main thread in those application is required to have Single Thread Apartment model, which ensures it.

Comment: Great answer with in depth explanation of the implementation details. I'm curious how the fiber part works. Could you share some pointers?